# mySQL populate table with missing rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables for my game script, one is a database of all the weapons ingame (`db_firearms`) and the other is a list of the weapons in the stores (`store_firearms`).

### db_firearms

(the `store` field says whether it will appear in stores, 0 = no, 1=yes)

```
id    name      store
-----------------------
1     Pistol    1
2     Shotgun   1
3     Sniper    0
```

### store_firearms

(`weapon` field relates to the id of the weapon in db_firearms)

```
id    city      weapon
-----------------------
1     Miami     1
2     Miami     2
3     New York  2
```

What I want to do, is populate the `store_firearms` table with each MISSING weapon from the `db_firearms` table with store=1 (where city= $city).

What's the best way to do a query for this in mySQL?

Comment: You will need to create a "store" column in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Completely botched that first try, using `NOT EXISTS` works.

```
INSERT INTO store_firearms (City, Weapon)
SELECT $city, F.Id
FROM db_firearms F        
WHERE F.Store = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM store_firearms WHERE City = $city AND Weapon = F.Id)
```

If $city were 'New York', this would insert 'New York', 1 into store_firearms

Comment: its giving me problems with that SELECT $city bit, saying it's not a valid db field

Comment: $city was just the placeholder for whatever city you are inserting, 'New York' for example.  A parameter to the query.

Comment: Yeah but its running `SELECT New York, F.Id FROM db_firearms F`

Comment: `SELECT '$city', F.Id` then?  Not sure how you're actually calling this query, whether or not you'd need to insert the quotes yourself.  Would need to do the same for ...`WHERE City = '$city'`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  ID, Name, Store
FROM    db_firearms
WHERE   STORE = 1 AND
        ID NOT IN 
            (SELECT weapon 
            FROM store_firearms
            WHERE city = $city)
```